# Element reference in 2 elements

Tags: xsd

I don't know how to title my question.

I have an XSD which contains the following elements

```
 <xs:element name="abc">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ele1"/>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

 <xs:element name="xyz">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ele1"/>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

 <xs:element name="ele1">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

The question is for element `xyz` `ID` is mandatory whereas for `abc` it is not; how can I specify this in the XSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ID is a unique identifier for the content repeated under the "container", then you could set a xs:key constraint for the xyz like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="abc">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ele1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="xyz">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ele1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="PK_xyz">
            <xs:selector xpath="ele1"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ele1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then, invalid XML because ID is missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xyz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ele1 ID="1"/>
    <ele1 />
</xyz>
```

Error message:

```
Error occurred while loading [], line 5 position 3
The identity constraint 'PK_xyz' validation has failed. Either a key is missing or the existing key has an empty node.
Document3.xml is invalid.
```

Invalid because it is duplicate (this is the downside, if the above assumption on uniqueness doesn't stand true):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xyz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ele1 ID="1"/>
    <ele1 ID="1"/>
</xyz>
```

Error:

```
Error occurred while loading [], line 5 position 3
There is a duplicate key sequence '1' for the 'PK_xyz' key or unique identity constraint.
Document3.xml is invalid.
```

Working sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xyz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ele1 ID="1"/>
    <ele1 ID="2"/>
</xyz>
```